# HTML hidden elements

Tags: python, html

I'm actually trying to code a little "GPS" and actually I couldn't use Google API because of the daily restriction.

I decided to use a site "viamichelin" which provide me the distance between two adresses. I created a little code to fetch all the URL adresses I needed like this :

```
import pandas

import numpy as np

df = pandas.read_excel('C:\Users\Bibi\Downloads\memoire\memoire.xlsx', sheet_name='Clients')

df2= pandas.read_excel('C:\Users\Bibi\Downloads\memoire\memoire.xlsx', sheet_name='Agences')

matrix=df.as_matrix(columns=None)

clients = np.squeeze(np.asarray(matrix))

matrix2=df2.as_matrix(columns=None)

agences = np.squeeze(np.asarray(matrix2))

compteagences=0

comptetotal=0

for j in agences:

    compteclients=0

    for i in clients:

        print agences[compteagences]

        print clients[compteclients]

        url ='https://fr.viamichelin.be/web/Itineraires?departure='+agences[compteagences]+'&arrival='+clients[compteclients]+'&arrivalId=34MTE1MnJ5ZmQwMDMzb3YxMDU1ZDFvbGNOVEF1TlRVNU5UUT1jTlM0M01qa3lOZz09Y05UQXVOVFl4TlE9PWNOUzQzTXpFNU5nPT1jTlRBdU5UVTVOVFE9Y05TNDNNamt5Tmc9PTBqUnVlIEZvbmQgZGVzIEhhbGxlcw==&index=0&vehicle=0&type=0&distance=km&currency=EUR&highway=false&toll=false&vignette=false&orc=false&crossing=true&caravan=false&shouldUseTraffic=false&withBreaks=false&break_frequency=7200&coffee_duration=1200&lunch_duration=3600&diner_duration=3600&night_duration=32400&car=hatchback&fuel=petrol&fuelCost=1.393&allowance=0&corridor=&departureDate=&arrivalDate=&fuelConsumption='

        print url

        compteclients+=1

        comptetotal+=1

    compteagences+=1
```

All my datas are on Excel that's why I used the pandas library. I have all the URL's needed for my project.

Although, I would like to extract the number of kilometers needed but there's a little problem. In the source code, I don't have the information I need, so I can't extract it with Python... The site is presented like this: 
[Michelin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T4CNs.png)

When I click on "inspect" I can find the information needed (on the left) but I can't on the source code (on the right) ... Can someone provide me some help? 
[Itinerary](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bwvMJ.png)

I have already tried this, without succeeding :

```
import os

import csv

import requests

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

requete = requests.get("https://fr.viamichelin.be/web/Itineraires?departure=Rue%20Lebeau%2C%20Liege%2C%20Belgique&departureId=34MTE1Mmc2NzQwMDM0NHoxMDU1ZW44d2NOVEF1TmpNek5ERT1jTlM0MU5qazJPQT09Y05UQXVOak16TkRFPWNOUzQxTnpBM01nPT1jTlRBdU5qTXpOREU9Y05TNDFOekEzTWc9PTBhUnVlIExlYmVhdQ==&arrival=Rue%20Rys%20De%20Mosbeux%2C%20Trooz%2C%20Belgique&arrivalId=34MTE1MnJ5ZmQwMDMzb3YxMDU1ZDFvbGNOVEF1TlRVNU5UUT1jTlM0M01qa3lOZz09Y05UQXVOVFl4TlE9PWNOUzQzTXpFNU5nPT1jTlRBdU5UVTVOVFE9Y05TNDNNamt5Tmc9PTBqUnVlIEZvbmQgZGVzIEhhbGxlcw==&index=0&vehicle=0&type=0&distance=km&currency=EUR&highway=false&toll=false&vignette=false&orc=false&crossing=true&caravan=false&shouldUseTraffic=false&withBreaks=false&break_frequency=7200&coffee_duration=1200&lunch_duration=3600&diner_duration=3600&night_duration=32400&car=hatchback&fuel=petrol&fuelCost=1.393&allowance=0&corridor=&departureDate=&arrivalDate=&fuelConsumption=")

page = requete.content

soup = BeautifulSoup(page, "html.parser")

print soup
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the inspector for the page, the actual routing is done via a JavaScript invocation to [this rather long URL](https://vmrest.viamichelin.com/apir/10/iti.json/fra/geom;header;roadsheet?distUnit=m&itit=0&veht=0&stepList=1%3Ae%3A5.57072%3A50.63341%3B1%3Ae%3A5.72926%3A50.55954%3B&avoidExpressWays=false&avoidBorders=false&avoidTolls=false&avoidCCZ=false&avoidORC=false&avoidPass=false&avoidClosedRoad=true&currency=EUR&data=geom;header;roadsheet&favMotorways=false&fuelCost=1.393&fuelConsump=6.8:5.6:5.6&itineraryFuelType=petrol&fullMapOpt=300:300:true:true:true&indemnite=0&multipleIti=true&stepMapOpt=300:300:true:true:true&traffic=AUT;BEL;CHE;DEU;DNK;ESP;FIN;FRA;GBR;ITA;LUX;NLD;NOR;POL;SWE&isCostFctUsingTraffic=false&sortFDRsByTraffic=false&timeLimitTDP=0&distanceLimitTDP=undefined&itineraryVehiculeType=hatchback&wCaravan=false&withSecurityAdv=true&shouldUseTraffic=false&costCategory=car&isMotorVehicle=true&lg=fra&obfuscation=false&charset=UTF-8&ie=UTF-8&authKey=JSBS20110216111214120400892678&nocache=1531733870014&callback=JSE.HTTP.asyncRequests[1]._scriptLoaded).

The data you need seems to be in that response, starting from `_scriptLoaded(`. (Since it's a JavaScript object literal, you can use Python's built-in JSON library to load the data into a `dict`.)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I'll try to do so !